# SQL if one of GROUPed rows includes A choose it else choose what's left

Tags: sql

The table looks like that:

```
|ID  |status  |Date      |
|1   |declined|01.01.2010|
|1   |declined|04.01.2010|
|1   |approved|06.01.2010|
|2   |approved|05.02.2010|
|3   |NULL    |05.02.2010|
```

So I wanna group them by ID but at the same time I want to get the latest status for each group
I tried using "Having" but it didn't work for me (I don't know how to use group on everything except status, and to choose only the latest value of status) for each group

Expected result:

```
|ID  |status  |Date      |
|1   |approved|06.01.2010|
|2   |approved|05.02.2010|
|3   |NULL    |05.02.2010|
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What other results do you want (e.g. total number of rows, final status...)?  Do you have an example of the results you are looking for from the example data you provided?

Comment: Based on the example provided above the result should contain all of the mentioned columns (ID, Status, Date) but only with 3 rows (1 Approved Date + 2 % + 3%). So basically where ID has several statuses I want to get rid of all statuses except for the last one (by date)

But if I simply GROUP BY ID, MAX(Date) I can't skip status (so it will choose only the latest one) if it makes sense (I'm new to SQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from yourtable t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from yourtable t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

Comment: I tried to implement this in my table but looks like my SQL knowledge doesn't allow me to do it properly so I get the following mistake (Table name "t" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request)

Comment: @Vlad . . . `t` is just an alias intended to mean your table.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, I'm just not bright enough here to understand how to implement it in my query as I don't have a table but I have a query that has the following structure:
SELECT
.....
FROM
LEFT JOIN
WHERE
GROUP BY

So there is no name of a table, there is just a query...

Comment: @Vlad . . . Use a CTE:  `with t as (<your query here>) select t.* from t where . . . `.

Answer (score 0):

IS ID a group within the context of your question?

The query down here shows the id's that have *approved* or *null* as status.
Id's (or groups) are displayed in ascending order.

```
SELECT * FROM `t1` 
WHERE status ='approved' OR status ='NULL'
ORDER BY date ASC
```

example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b61dc18af6193dc30cd9692679e6513e

Comment: My bad for not being clear on what result is expected I edited the question

Comment: Thank you for your update, i hope the most recent edit works for you.